# Creating my custom plugin and register it locally

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to create my own aurelia plugin , I created a folder my-plugin and put the `index.js` inside it . I added it in the main.js with `use.plugin("my-plugin")` .
When run I get can't find my-plugin.
I added it to jspm section under the package.json but when call jspm install I get Install of my-plugin to my-plugin has no registry property provided.

How I can use the plugin locally without going throw jspm.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method to add internal plugins was renamed `feature` to resolve an issue with the module loader spec.

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .feature('my-plugin');

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```